# iPad Movie Player Problem

Tags: ipad

I am playing mp4 files in iPad using MPMoviePlayerController. I have a view connected in IB to play the video files. The problem is that if one of the files is audio-only, it plays fine, but then videos that play after the audio file do not show the play/pause/seek controls.

I am doing this to initialize the view:

```
    self.theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
 [self.viewForMovie addSubview:theMovie.view];
```

Has anyone seen this behavior or have an idea how I can get the video controls to reappear?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the control type with

```
self.theMovie.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault
```

These are the available options:

```
MPMovieControlStyleNone
MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded
MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
MPMovieControlStyleDefault
```

Details here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html